# Why there is no linker error while defining classes with the same name in two different cpp files?

Tags: c++, linker

everyone!

Please consider the following peace of code:

```
   $ cat a.cpp
   #include <stdio.h>

   struct A
   {
      void foo() { printf("a.cpp: A::foo()\n");}
   };

   void fooA()
   {
      A a;
      a.foo();
   }

   $ cat b.cpp
   #include <stdio.h>

   struct A
   {
      void foo() { printf("b.cpp: A::foo()\n");}
   };

   void fooB()
   {
      A a;
      a.foo();
   }

   $ cat main.cpp 
   void fooA();
   void fooB();

   int main()
   {
         fooA();
         fooB();
         return 0;
   }

   $ g++ main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp 

   $ ./a.out
   a.cpp: A::foo()
   a.cpp: A::foo()
```

As you can see there is no warnings or errors from linker, but on runtime we receive not what we expected. I check it on gcc 4.8.1 and msvc 2013.
With simple free functions linker will raise an error in such case. But if it a method of the class it doesn't.

Why it works like this?

Comment: You should enable `-Wall`, good question though.

Comment: Because linkers don't link classes.

Comment: Violating ODR does not lead to "peace of code" :P

Comment: You could simplify the example by having the class in a header file included in both source files. Then to make definitions different in `printf` use some name like TEXT which you would `#define` differently before including the header in both sources. But that is just a side note.

Answer (score 3):

Functions defined inside a class definition are implicitly inline, so you're allowed to define them in multiple translation units.

The definitions must be identical, but the compiler isn't required to diagnose that since it that would be impossible when processing one unit at a time. You broke that rule, giving undefined behaviour.

To use the same name for different entities in different translation units, you could put each in a different namespace, or an unnamed namespace which is local to the translation unit:

```
namespace /* optional name */ {
    class A {
        // whatever you want
    };
}
```

Comment: Or proper, named namespaces.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in some contexts, that just kicks the can down the road -- a unique name is unique, be it a class or a namespace.  Unless you name it `full_path_a_cpp_private_namespace`.  If you are writing a helper class within `a.cpp`, giving it a brief name can be useful, and anonymous namespaces are a compiler-understood way to say "this is private to this compilation unit" (it can even ease linking overhead issues, as a smart compiler knows no other compilation unit could possibly have access to the name)

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, I know what anonymous namespaces are.